# question on <html:multibox>?

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I have a JSP where data is shown by use of a for:each loop. In this loop I have a multibox tag which will display checkboxes next to each corresponding row. A user will have the ability to select all or a few or none of the checkboxes and click print.

```
JSP PAGE LOOK :--

MULTIBOX PERSONNAME INVITATIONLIST
------------- ------------------ ---------------------
PROPERTY:-- [STRINGARRAY] [STRING] [STRINGARRAY]

<table><tr>
<logic:iterate id="message" name="MessageForm" property="nameList">

<td>
<html:multibox name="FORM" property="GETINVITATIONS">
<bean:write name="FORM" property="name" />
<bean:write name="FORM" property="selectedInv" /> <------ how to add String array to 'GETINVITATIONS'?
</html:multibox>
</td>

<td><bean:write name="FORM" property="name" /></td> [NAME]
<td>

<bean:define id="List" name="FORM" property="invLst" type="java.util.ArrayList" />
<html:select style="width:200px;" name="FORM" property="selectedInv" styleId="selectedInv1" multiple="true"> [MULTIPLE INVITATION NAMES]
<html:options name="List"/>
</html:select>

</td>
</logic:iterate>
</tr>
</table>
```

Only name is being added to the `GETINVITATIONS`; `selectedInv` is not adding to it. Only name printing in the console. How to do it?

Comment: I'm assuming that selectedInv is String[], is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this?

```
<td>
<html:multibox name="FORM" property="GETINVITATIONS">
<bean:write name="FORM" property="name" />
<logic:iterate id="inv" name="FORM" property="selectedInv">
    <bean:write name="inv" />&nbsp;
</logic:iterate>
</html:multibox>
</td>
```

Basically, you're iterating through the the `selectedInv` field (which is an array of String) and write it to JSP (using bean:write).